# Automatic Weights completely wrong

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I attached my character to my armature with automatic weights and everything works as expected.

However, if I do the same with its clothes, the weights are completely wrong. Somehow, the hem of his shirt is connected to his left forearm.

I then tried to manually paint the weights instead, but it won't let me select any of the bones in weight painting mode. What could I be missing here? (Yes, I did select the armature, then the model when going into weight painting)

[image]
[image]

EDIT: This just got stranger. I managed to paint the weights manually, but the problem still happens. What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Autoweights don't work well on multiple, disconnected meshes.  Consider applying a data transfer modifier from your body to copy weights from it instead.

Comment: @Nathan can you elaborate? (ELI5?) How would you use the data transfer modifier from the body to copy weights, to resolve the problem caused by multiple, disconnected meshes?

Comment: @Brad Graham Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111476/rigging-clothes-to-a-character